# Adding line break in displayed math, only one equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, line-breaking

This question may seem like a duplicate, but I haven't seen any satisfactory answer in similar questions.

Is there a way to add a line break in displayed math mode *without* using multiple-line environments such as `gather` or `eqnarray`? I want to display an equation that spans multiple lines inside an `equation` environment (so that the entire thing only gets one number).

My current code:

```
\begin{equation}
   A_i=A_0-\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}[(2^i\cdot3)\cdot\frac{s_i^2}{18}\cdot sin(\alpha)]=%
   \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}[(2^i\cdot3)\cdot\frac{(\frac{s_0}{3^i})^2}{18}\cdot sin(180º-\frac{120º}{2^i})]=%
   \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}[(2^i\cdot3)\cdot\ddfrac{s_0^2}{18\cdot3^{2i}}\cdot sin(180º-\frac{120º}{2^i})]
\end{equation}
```

This "overflows" the line:
[image: current code pdf output]

I want to add a line break in between (after one of the = signs), but still have the whole thing labelled as (4.7).

Comment: \begin{multline} ... \end{multline}

Comment: Have you seen this question and answers therein: [How can I split an equation over two (or more) lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/117534)? Another example: [Long equation needs to be split and aligned to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359364/117534)

Comment: @Troy No, I hadn't. So this is a duplicate now. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @user94293 Works, thanks. Is the staircaise-like shape that this environment produces a convention in maths publishing?

Comment: No, just close it as a duplicate is okay.